# Cannot populate my ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-viewholder

So my layout inflation consists in a `content_frame` -> `listview_fragment` -> `list_row_item`

On `MainActivity` I am supposed to choose which mode shall I display and I'm forcing it for debug reasons

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{


    //region Properties
    private GoogleMap map;
    private static final int LAYOUT_CHOOSER = 123;
    private static final String TAG="MainActivity";
    //endregion


    //region Methods
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);


        if(LAYOUT_CHOOSER == 1){
            Log.v(TAG, "Im on the MapMode");
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.content_frame, new SecurityMapFragment())
                    .commit();
        }

        else {
            Log.v(TAG, "Im on the ListMode");
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.content_frame, new SecurityListFragment())
                    .commit();

        }
```

It will call the `SecurityListFragment` class

```
public class SecurityListFragment extends BaseFragment {

private TestAdapter mTestAdapter;
private SecurityResponse securityResponse;
private FetchDataInterface dataInterface;

public SecurityListFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.v("ListFragment", "I entered the onCreateView!");

    final View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.security_listview_fragment, container, false);
    Log.v("ListFragment", "rootView created");


    //set adapter
    ListView lista = (ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.listview_security);
    lista.setAdapter(mTestAdapter);
    Log.v("dasd", "asdasdasd");//for breakpoint usage
    return root;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    dataInterface = RetrofitUtils.createGsonRetrofitInterface();
    RetrofitUtils.testGetPspDataFromApi(new Callback<SecurityResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<SecurityResponse> call, Response<SecurityResponse> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                securityResponse = response.body();
                mTestAdapter = new TestAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_security_row_item, securityResponse.features);

                Log.v("ListFragment", "great success");



            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<SecurityResponse> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    }, dataInterface);
    Log.v("adasdadsa","asdasdasdasdasasdas");//more breakpoint usage
}
```

It is in the `SecurityListFragment` class that I make my callback to get my data using the Retrofit lib. The callback is working fine and data is not corrupt, I've tested it on the other mode and it's able to create map objects according to the geolocation that it's given.

My `TestAdapter` class:

```
public class TestAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Feature> {

protected Context mContext;
protected int layoutResourceId;
protected List<Feature> mSecurityResponse;




public TestAdapter(Context context, int resourceId, List<Feature> objects) {
    super(context, resourceId, objects);

    this.layoutResourceId = resourceId;
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mSecurityResponse = objects;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    ViewHolder viewHolder;



    if(convertView==null){

        // inflate the layout
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        // well set up the ViewHolder
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.distance = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.security_list_distance);
        viewHolder.icon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.security_list_icon);
        viewHolder.name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.security_list_name);
        viewHolder.description = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.security_list_description);

        // store the holder with the view.
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    }else{
        // we've just avoided calling findViewById() on resource everytime
        // just use the viewHolder
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // object item based on the position
    Feature featureItem = mSecurityResponse.get(position);

    // assign values if the object is not null
    if(featureItem != null) {
        // get the TextView from the ViewHolder and then set the text (item name) and tag (item ID) values
        viewHolder.distance.setText("42"+ " km");
        viewHolder.description.setText(featureItem.attributes.description);
        viewHolder.name.setText(featureItem.attributes.name);
        viewHolder.icon.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

    }

    return convertView;
}
public static class ViewHolder{
    public  ImageView icon;
    public  TextView name;
    public  TextView description;
    public  TextView distance;
}
```

Almost forgot, here are the layouts that are used:

`content_frame` layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</FrameLayout>
```

The `security_listview_fragment`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview_security"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

And the `list_security_row_item`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/security_list_icon"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="20px">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/security_list_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/security_list_description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/security_list_distance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your `SecurityListFragment` as below

```
public class SecurityListFragment extends BaseFragment {

private TestAdapter mTestAdapter;
private SecurityResponse securityResponse;
private FetchDataInterface dataInterface;
private ListView lista;//**changed**

public SecurityListFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.v("ListFragment", "I entered the onCreateView!");

    final View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.security_listview_fragment, container, false);
    Log.v("ListFragment", "rootView created");


    //set adapter
    lista = (ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.listview_security);//**changed**

    Log.v("dasd", "asdasdasd");//for breakpoint usage
    return root;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    dataInterface = RetrofitUtils.createGsonRetrofitInterface();
    RetrofitUtils.testGetPspDataFromApi(new Callback<SecurityResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<SecurityResponse> call, Response<SecurityResponse> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                securityResponse = response.body();
                mTestAdapter = new TestAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_security_row_item, securityResponse.features);
              lista.setAdapter(mTestAdapter);//**changed**
                Log.v("ListFragment", "great success");



            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<SecurityResponse> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    }, dataInterface);
    Log.v("adasdadsa","asdasdasdasdasasdas");//more breakpoint usage
}
```

Comment: Will do, thank you for your help. I will respond soon enough after debug.

Comment: It worked, my layout is all f***ed up but I'm sure I can manage that. Thank you for your time and gratitude. I understand now how to deal with the adapter and the callback. Many thanks. Marked you as the answer ;)